# Opportunity report with Contacts with specific Activities

Tags: reporting, joined-reports

I want to make a report with Opportunity information. I want to filter out Opportunities where the Contact has an activity assigned to a specific User. Our activities are only linked to the contact, not to the Opportunity.

I couldn't figure out how to make a report type that links all three so I used two reports Contacts-Opportunities and Contacts-Activities and created a joined report. From there I could filter out contacts with the specific activities on one block, but that didn't eliminate the contact on the other side with the opportunity. Is this do-able? Am I over complicating it?